# Swift tuple as dictionary value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a following class which uses subscripts as its essentially a wrapper around Swift dictionary.

```
class STCTruthDict: NSObject, SequenceType {

  typealias IpRelationshipTuple = (String, String?)

  private var truthDict: [String : IpRelationshipTuple] = [ : ]

  subscript(key: String) -> IpRelationshipTuple? {
    get {
        return self.truthDict[key]
    }
    set {
        truthDict[key] = newValue
    }
  }

  // MARK: - Initializers

  override init() {
      super.init()
  }

func generate() -> DictionaryGenerator <String, IpRelationshipTuple> {
    return self.truthDict.generate()
}

}
```

I am trying to use this class and its subscripts from another class with following code:

```
private var truthDict: STCTruthDict?
.....
.....
.....

 // Get ip and userId
 let ipToBeAdded = responseData["ip"] as! String
 let userIdForIP = responseData["user_id"] as! String
 // update truth table
 let relationshipTuple = (ipToBeAdded, nil) as STCTruthDict.IpRelationshipTuple?
 self.truthDict[userIdForIP] = relationshipTuple
```

But I get an error saying:

```
“Cannot assign to immutable value of type ‘IpRelationshipTuple?’ “
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

This is the playground snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Your error is complaining about the usage of `ipRelationshipTuple`, but you have defined `IpRelationshipTuple`. Notice the difference in case on the first character. When I paste your code into a playground (and implement `generate()` properly), it runs without error.

Comment: @IanMacDonald : that was a typo. I have update the question. But I still see the error. I have updated the question with my generate method as well. I haven't tried playground though

Comment: I have added my playground error as well in the question

Comment: Because your `truthDict` is defined optional, you'll need to unwrap it. I don't get the same error as you, but you should try `truthDict!["you"]` or remove the optional from the definition altogether.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Thanks. you are right. I missed that part. Thanks a lot. Can you add this comment as the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: By the way, you are defining both the dictionary and the tuple as optionals (lines 46 and 49 in the screenshot above). From the context of your playground file it does not seem to be necessary and perhaps you could remove that and simplify your code.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. I just copy pasted stuff from different files to test in playground. I have corrected it now though. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `truthDict` is defined optional, you'll need to unwrap it. I don't get the same error as you, but you should try `truthDict!["you"]` or remove the optional from the definition altogether.

```
var truthDict = STCTruthDict()
```

or

```
truthDict!["you"] = relationshipTuple
//       ^
```